# How to create interface for C++ application with XAML?

Tags: c++, xaml

How to create interface for C++ application with XAML? (I SEARCH FOR SOME APP LIKE EXPRESSION BLEND (OR even beter a plug in for it))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Pro 2008 does support C++ .Net and XAML interface designer so it should do what you are looking for.

PS : Visual Studio 2010 is going to be released soon. I never tried XAML with this one but it should have a better support.